# Show uniform convergence on closed interval

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Let $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of functions with $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as: $$f_n(x)=e^{-(x-n)^2}.$$
**a)** Show that the sequence is pointwise convergent towards zero on $\mathbb{R}$.
**b)** Show that the sequence is uniformly convergent towards zero on $[a,b]$ where $a<b$.
**c)** Show that the sequence is not uniformly convergent towards zero on $\mathbb{R}$.

**My solutions for a) and c):**

**a)** For all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have that:
$$f_n(x)=e^{-(x-n)^2}=\frac{1}{e^{(x-n)^2}}\to\frac{1}{e^\infty}=\frac{1}{\infty}=0 \quad\text{for }n\to\infty.$$
Hence $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is pointwise convergent towards $f(x)=0$.

**c)** We know that $e^x\geq 1$ for $x\geq 0$, and that $e^x=1\Leftrightarrow x=0$. Since $(x-n)^2\geq 0$ we have that:
$$f_n(x)=e^{-(x-n)^2}=\frac{1}{e^{(x-n)^2}}\leq 1,\qquad e^{-(x-n)^2}=1 \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad x=n.$$
This means that $f_n(x)$ reaches its maximum in $f_n(n)=1$. Since $e^x>0$ we have that:
\begin{align*}
&d_\mathbb{R}(f,f_n)=\sup|f(x)-f_n(x)|=\sup|0-e^{-(x-n)^2}|=\sup (e^{-(x-n)^2})\\
&=\max f_n(x)=1.
\end{align*}
We then have that:
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}d_\mathbb{R}(f,f_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}1=1\neq 0 \quad\text{for }x\in\mathbb{R}.
\end{align*}
Since $d_\mathbb{R}(f,f_n)$ does not converge towards zero, the sequence is not uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$.

**Can anybody help me with b)?**

Comment: Can you calculate $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in\left[a,b\right]}\left|f\left(x\right)\right|}$?

Comment: @Guy That would be 0? But shouldn't I rather find $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in [a,b]}|f(x)-f_n(x)|}$?

Comment: Yes, but here you showed in a) that $f(x)=0$, so it's equivalent :)

Comment: But $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{[a,b]}|f(x)-f_n(x)|}=\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{[a,b]}|f_n(x)|}$. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part $\text{(b)}$, consider what happens when $a\le x\le b$ and $n\gg b:$
$$
e^{-(x-n)^2} = e^{-((x-b)-(n-b))^2} \le e^{-(n-b)^2} \to 0 \text{ as } n\to\infty. \tag 1
$$
So think about

- how to prove the inequality in $(1)$ and
- the fact that the quantity asserted to approach $0$ in $(1)$ does not depend on $x.$

The way I thought of the inequality in $(1)$ is by thinking about what the graph of $x\mapsto e^{-(x-n)^2}$ looks like. It's "bell curve" centered at $n.$ When $n\gg b$ then $b$ is in one of its very thin tails and the value of the function gets smaller as $x$ gets farther from $n;$ thus is smaller everywhere else in $[a,b]$ than at $b.$